# Some Images not loading Elastic Beanstalk Php

Tags: php, image, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed my first Elastic Beanstalk application on AWS. It is a simple PHP application and for the most part everything is working. However, some of my images are not loading (404s). This seems kind of random because half of the images do work, and the other half don't. They live in the same directory, and are all .png files. Not sure what could be at play here; is there anyway to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem. The images that were not loading were capital .PNG files (instead of .png). Windows was fine with this, which is why it worked on my local xampp server, but Linux was not happy with this.